# How to write a oracle sql for the date period to get the all the days balance should be above zero?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im unable to build the logic to get the the distinct acctno for the period balance  should be above zero

```
Acctno   date         balance
123      01-Aug-20     1000
123      02-Aug-20      500
...      ...            ...
456      01-Aug-20      45000
456      02-Aug-20      (1000)
```

if we consider the 123 account have an credit balance ( balance >0 ) over the period &
456 account one day account is a debit balance (balance less than zero )
how can i build the sql ?
My answer for that above eg is : 123
(For the month of August need to check on every day balance)

Comment: I don't get, how you differentiate between `123` and `456` ?

Comment: It's a unique number

Comment: No what I am asking is , from the sample data how `123` is expected where `456` is not ?

Comment: for 456 account 02-aug-2020 balance is less than zero, where we consider the 123 account for august month every date the balance is above zero

Comment: Is it like a negative value ? why it is represented within `()` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 That is often how accountants represent negative balances on a balance sheet. Oracle has the (undocumented) `PT` format model to support that type of numeric output.

Comment: Do you always have exactly one row per day or do we need to fill in gaps using the most recent value? I.e. if there was no `2020-08-01` row would we need to consider the data from `2020-07-31` to determine if `2020-08-01` had a positive or negative balance?

Answer (score 0):

You could group by id and month and find the minimum balance.

Then, if minimum balance if greater than (or equals) zero  it means that there are no negative balances
in the group...

Something along this lines:

```
with mydata as ( 
select  123 acctno ,   '01/08/20' d,     1000 balance from dual
union all
select  123 acctno ,   '02/08/20' d,     500 balance from dual
union all
select  456 acctno ,   '01/08/20' d,     4500 balance from dual
union all
select  456 acctno ,   '02/08/20' d,     -1000 balance from dual
)
select * from (
select acctno,  to_char(to_date(d,'dd/mm/rrrr'),'MM'),min(balance) mm ,count(d) cnt   
from mydata 
group by acctno,to_char(to_date(d,'dd/mm/rrrr'),'MM')
)
where mm>=0 --and cnt=(number of days in the month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as below -

```
 Select distinct Acctno
 from mytable T1
 Where T1.date between to_date('01-AUG-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('31-AUG-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
 and not exists 
      (Select 1 from
        mytable T2
        Where T2.date between to_date('01-AUG-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('31-AUG-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
        And T2.balance <= 0
        And T1.Acctno = T2.Acctno) ;
```

EDIT : This is just an alternative way to achieve the output you desire by using self-join. Group by method works as well for this case. Also, I agree with some of the other comments that the column “Date” is a poor choice of name since it’s a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select acctno
from mytable
where acctdate > date '2020-08-01' and acctdate < date '2020-09-01'
group by acctno
having min(balance) >= 0
```

The query filters the table on the month of August, and bring accounts whose balance never dropped below `0`.

Note: `date` is a language keyword (that's the name of a datatype), hence a poor choice for a column name. I renamed it to `acctdate` in the query.